# paymentQueue: updatedTransactions: not called

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have recently released my first app after 2.5 years of development (a roguelike) and I am now having difficulty restoring a nonconsumable purchase:

I have a "restore purchases" button that calls this method just fine:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Then a prompt pops up requesting my user name and password, so I enter my test account information.

However, that is all that happens.  The app doesn't crash as xcode shows it still running fine, but this method never gets called:

```
-(void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions;
```

I am able to make consumable purchases and even the non-consumable purchase can be made normally, but when I delete the app from my device, reinstall and try to restore, the paymentQueue: updatedTransactions: function above never gets called while everything else seems to be called normally.

Can anyone identify my error?

Comment: paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished also not being called.

Comment: Have you checked whether your test user may be broken (i.e. did you try with a new one)?

Comment: No, I have not.  I will try that now . . .

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  I created the user and tried to restore a purchase without first purchasing it.  Again, I am prompted and enter my username and password and then nothing happens.  No call to paymentQueue: restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:; No call to paymentQueue: updatedTransactions:; or any of the other functions, all of which have breakpoints and NSLogs; the app isn't crashed or anything either as I still see it acting in xcode.

Comment: On itunesconnect, my in app purchase is red and says "waiting for screenshot"; could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Have you registered a transaction observer at launch?

Answer (score 17):

Are you calling `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:myObject]` to tell the defaultQueue that you are to be notified of transaction updates/events? I just recently had a similar problem occur to me, and it took a couple of days and multiple tutorials to find the error. Hope this helps!

Comment: That solved it for me!

Comment: when ask defaultQueue ?

Answer (score 3):

Note that Store Kit testing does not work in the Simulator. You don't say whether this is happening in the Simulator or on a device, but my experience is that testing in the Simulator won't cut it. (It's unclear to me whether this is a deliberate policy on Apple's part or a Simulator bug.)